# Why does browser show me only one alert box

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Down here you can see my code i have problem that only show me 1 alert box even i put index++. What is solution of my problem.

MY CODE

```js
var questions = [
  {
    text: "Da li je javascript dobar jezik",
    correctAnswer : true

  },
  {
    text: "Da li je css programski jezik",
    correctAnswer : true
  },
  {
  text: "Da li je php programski jezik",
  correctAnswer: true
  }
]
var index = 0;
var score = 0;
function quiz(){
  var quizQuestion = confirm(questions[index].text);
  if (quizQuestion === questions[index].correctAnswer){
    score++;
  }
  index++;
  if (index == questions[index]){
    index=0;
  }
}
quiz();
```

I exepted to show me 3 alert boxes but only show me one

Comment: `confirm` is only ever called once.  Did you mean to write a *loop* somewhere?

Comment: Each time you call `quiz()` it will ask the next question. But you only call it once.

Comment: i know that i call one but it should on browser appear three times without calling function three times

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep going through the questions, call `quiz` again at the end of the function if the last index has not been reached.

```js
function quiz() {
    // ...
    if (index < questions.length) quiz();
}
```

```js
var questions = [{
    text: "Da li je javascript dobar jezik",
    correctAnswer: true
  },
  {
    text: "Da li je css programski jezik",
    correctAnswer: true
  },
  {
    text: "Da li je php programski jezik",
    correctAnswer: true
  }
]
var index = 0;
var score = 0;

function quiz() {
  var quizQuestion = confirm(questions[index].text);
  if (quizQuestion === questions[index].correctAnswer) {
    score++;
  }
  index++;
  if (index < questions.length) quiz();
}
quiz();
console.log('Score', score);
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT, but i did exatly like you writte but same thing

Comment: @nemanja Did you run the code snippet in my answer? It works.

Comment: no i run the code in my text editor it does not work

Comment: @nemanja Did you run the code snippet, though? If that works, then that's an unrelated issue on your side.

Comment: it works i did not writte properly length